# Grid responsive image disintegrate in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, image, responsive, slideshow

I create a website in Grid, this is good but when my JS slideshow go to the next image, my contentboxes is disintegrate.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk7xj.png)

Comment: Slideshow is works but my contentboxes (or cards) is disintegrate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.